# R: Extract letters from a string only one time after the first occurrence

Tags: r, string, extract, gsub

I am trying to do something relatively simple, but nothing I have tried is working. I have googled my task and I just cannot seem get my code to work.

I am attempting to extract letters only the first time they are present in the following sentence:

```
 text <- 'i ride my bike'
```

I have tried the following code:

```
 gsub('([[:alpha:]])\\1{1}', '\\1', text)
```

and it does not achieve what I would like. I want the final result to be:

```
 i r d e m y b k
```

I only want the first occurrence of the letter. Things I have found on Google are more along the lines of reducing "hellllllo" to "hello" but I would want "helo." I hope I'm making sense!

Thanks everyone!

Comment: `c(unique(as.data.frame(strsplit(text,""))))[[1]]` Gives you what you're after, including the first space.

Comment: Or perhaps: `unique(strsplit(text,"")[[1]])`

Comment: I knew there had to be a more simple way about it!

Comment: Grothendieck and Badger: Thank you guys so much!

Answer (score 1):

Based on Badger's and Gabor's answers and removing the first space with `grep`:

```
grep(" ",unique(strsplit(text,"")[[1]]),value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)
[1] "i" "r" "d" "e" "m" "y" "b" "k"
```